# Error 500 in FastCGI on PHP

Tags: php, webserver, fastcgi

I recently changed server.
This my new server using FastCGI to interpret PHP.
However, much that I brought from the old server is giving this error again, and the problem is that FastCGI does not return the error to debug, it just returns a "500 internal server error".

With that I'm not exactly sure what line to correct the error occurred.
I have scripts immense, which makes unfeasible review the entire a Code.

Already tried using

try {.. }

in known errors, but still FastCGI returns the 500 error.

I'm not a server administrator to power on mecher environment variables, is there any way to work around these errors from within PHP?

Comment: check your server error logs and virtual host file everything is proper check your .htaccess file also

Comment: Is it possible that there is something wrong in your .htaccess files or your new server has AllowRewrite set to None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error may be cause because you didn't set the proper permissions for the directory.

You should set the proper permissions and then try run the script. It should work.

Try running simple  php file to see if it shows this error. If so then change permissions. If not then check the logs because the problem may be in your script.

You can also set display_errors to 1 in php.ini, htaccess or inside script

in **php.ini** look for `error_reporting` and `display_errors`

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = 1
```

Comment: Thank you all.
The administration of this new server configurations leave some well hidden in the user panel.
I found the place where it sets the display of errors in PHP.

Now I know exactly where the problems are in my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your code, it'll turn error reporting on.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you all.
The administration of this new server configurations leave some well hidden in the user panel.
I found the place where it sets the display of errors in PHP.

Now I know exactly where the problems are in my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I had the proper permissions.

What fixed my problem was to download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 **x86**.

I have **PHP in x86** so I downloaded **VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe**.

I had just x64 before solving my issue. Installing VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe solved the problem and now I have both.

I hope it helps!

Yo can download VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679